# Column A showing ALL rows, despite filter, after transfered to another workbook, while column B and C correctly show only the filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie as it comes to Excel-VBA and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong. Completely puzzled. I've got an Excel-workbook Test.xlsm with 4 rows. From Test I trigger a macro "Transfer()" which first filters in field 5 (column E) at search term "Fiets". The result is 2 rows matching "Fiets". From these 2 rows the first 3 columns (A, B, C) including the heading need to be transfered to the workbook "Export_LI".
The strange thing is that first 3 times or so the result is what you expect, but after 4th time or so the result is column A showing ALL 4 rows from Test in Export_LI (so not correct).  Column B is showing just the 2 rows (correct) and column C is also showing just the 2 rows (also correct). So why is column A showing ALL rows from Test in Export_LI, despite the filter? (and B and C showing only the 2 rows which is correct).

```
Sub Transfer()
' Filter field 5 (column E) to get rows containing term "Fiets"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*Fiets*", Operator:=xlAnd

Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\raymo\Documents\AB\Export_LI.xlsx"

' Transfer columns to Export_LI
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Export_LI.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("B")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Export_LI.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("B")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Export_LI.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you post the macro code... ;)

Comment: Hi Rory, I gladly would like to but I can't see where. It can't be done in comment-box and not in the body of the message. I must overlook something I guess....

Comment: Gave you an idea of where to put your code @Ray

Comment: Thanx Notus_Panda. Succeeded :-)

Comment: Running a slightly edited version (tested in the same workbook, used `.Columns("A:C")` to do all 3 at once and had no issue spamming the code 10+ times. So I can't recreate your issue. Are you sure ActiveSheet is always the one you want?

Comment: Are you sure the autofilter includes column A?

Comment: @Paul, the autofilter is set on column E (field 5), and the columns to be transferred are A, B and C (if that is what you mean). But I think I've got the solution from Notus_Panda (I'll comment on that)

Comment: @Notus_Panda, I altered the code in `.Columns("A:C")` as you did and this seems to be working! The only thing is that the columns to be transferred are not consecutive.  So if I want A, B, C and E (not D), what to do? I tried `Columns("A:C, E")` but that's not working, got an error.  And btw, ActiveSheet is indeed the one I always want (there's only one sheet). But I'm a big step further now, many thanx!

Comment: What Paul meant is when you set an Autofilter and the columns aren't all filled header-wise, it'll stop at the last non-empty headers from the range you activated it on. However, in a listobject this shouldn't be an issue since even if it was empty in the range, in the actual table you'd get "Column1" + there's automatically an autofilter over all columns of said table.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's bad practice copying entire columns like this, here's how you can exclude Column D and copy faster:

```
Sub Transfer()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Me.Worksheets("Test")
    Set wsDes = Me.Worksheets("Export_LI") 'change this to your need
    ' Filter field 5 (column E) to get rows containing term "Fiets"
    With wsSrc.ListObjects("Tabel1")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*Fiets*", Operator:=xlAnd
        '.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy wsDes.Range("A1")
        'this above line is if you'd want the entire table copied quicker
    End With
    
    Dim srcRng As Range, desRng As Range, lRow As Long
    
    lRow = wsSrc.Range("E" & wsSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row of table
    Set srcRng = Union(wsSrc.Range("A1:C" & lRow), wsSrc.Range("E1:E" & lRow))
    'make union of your desired ranges
    Set desRng = wsDes.Range("A1") 'not really needed if you're only using it once
    srcRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy desRng
End Sub
```

A little edit to suit your situation more:

```
Sub Transfer()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet, wbDes As Workbook
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    Set wbDes = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raymo\Documents\AB\Export_LI.xlsx")
    Set wsDes = wbDes.Worksheets("Export_LI")
    ' Filter field 5 (column E) to get rows containing term "Fiets"
    With wsSrc.ListObjects("Tabel1")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*Fiets*", Operator:=xlAnd
        '.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy wsDes.Range("A1")
        'this above line is if you'd want the entire table copied quicker
    End With
    
    Dim srcRng As Range, desRng As Range, lRow As Long
    
    lRow = wsSrc.Range("E" & wsSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row of table
    Set srcRng = Union(wsSrc.Range("A1:C" & lRow), wsSrc.Range("E1:E" & lRow))
    'make union of your desired ranges
    Set desRng = wsDes.Range("A1")
    srcRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy desRng
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx Notus. I tried but got an compile error: "invalid use of the keyword Me" (translated from Dutch). After that in the code I changed `Worksheet` and `Worksheets` in respectly `Workbook` and `Workbooks` - cause Test and Export_LI are Excel-files on their own - and I put the extension behind it (so: `Me. Workbooks("Test.xlsm")` and `Me.Workbooks("Export_LI.xlsx")`, but the same error appeared unfortunately. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, probably should've mentioned this code was in the `ThisWorkbook` code-page. `Me` used in ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook the code is in. `Me` in a Worksheet code-page would refer to the Worksheet and so on, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword).

Comment: Edited to a more suited-to-your-situation code

Comment: Hi Notus, in your edited code I changed the lines
`Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")` and
`Set wsDes = wbDes.Worksheets("Export_LI")` in resp
`Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` and
`Set wsDes = wbDes.Worksheets(1)`
(there's only one worksheet in both files) and it works perfectly now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to help :)